# Fill missing date and time in Python (pandas)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, datetime, missing-data

I have a large data set, a sample is given below. The data is recorded for `1 day` with `5-min` interval for `24 hours` for `3214 unique ids`.

- The `time and date` information is missing in some rows as shown in the image. Is there a way to automatically fill the missing date and time for every `unique_id`? Every unique id has 288 datetime values (5 min * 12 hr * 24 hr = `288` values per day with 5 min increment in time interval)
- Also, how to fill the missing `unqiue ids` with previous value?
- I am trying to fill the last column `VALUE` with empty cells.

I searched for the relevant answers [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49308251/filling-missing-rows), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41212273/pandaspython-fill-empty-cells-with-with-previous-row-value) but it did not work.

The most relent answer was [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47231496/pandas-fill-missing-dates-in-time-series?noredirect=1&lq=1), but the solutions are only for missing dates not for both date and times.

### `sample_data.csv`

```py
datetime    Unique_ID   VALUE
28/01/2018 2:05 105714  284
28/01/2018 2:10 105714  292
28/01/2018 2:15 105714  287
28/01/2018 2:20 105714  193
28/01/2018 2:25 105714  2348
28/01/2018 2:30 105714  284
28/01/2018 2:35 105714  286
28/01/2018 2:40 105714  293
28/01/2018 2:45 105714  229
28/01/2018 2:50 105714  2292
28/01/2018 2:55 105714  225
28/01/2018 4:45 105714  185
28/01/2018 4:50 105714  277
28/01/2018 4:55 105714  185
28/01/2018 5:00 105714  2435
28/01/2018 5:05 105714  273
28/01/2018 5:10 105714  2360
28/01/2018 5:15 105714  282
```

[image]

Comment: with what value would you like to fill the 'value' column

Comment: @Devakumarkp. With blank or empty cells like here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31470551/pythonpandas-fills-blanks-cells

Answer (score 1):

Here in `pandas` you can try:

Firstly get the index of `nan` values:

```
idx=df[df.isna().all(1)].index
```

Then use `ffill()` method:

```
df[['Unique_ID','datetime']]=df[['Unique_ID','datetime']].ffill()
```

Finally you can use `groupby()` method and `transform()` method:

```
df['VALUE']=df.groupby(['Unique_ID','datetime'],dropna=False).transform('last')
```

Now if you want to increment 'datetime' column value  by 5 mins which are filled by `ffill()` method then:

```
df.loc[idx,'datetime']=df.loc[idx,'datetime']+pd.to_timedelta(5,unit='m')
```

Comment: Updated my answer kindly have a look **:)**

Comment: The above solution doesn,t worked for me as it depends on `nan` values. The data I am trying doesn,t have `nan` value or any blank spaces. Rather a missing information between the time intervals as shown here. https://i.stack.imgur.com/xNcb5.png

Comment: For instance, there are `22 values of datetime are missing` in the above shared image. I am  trying for a solution which will automatically fill the `datetime` value with 5 min increment for 24 hrs (288 values in total for 24 hr).

Comment: next time pls be more specific and clear when asking question as no where in the question you are mentioning that missing is not refferring to `nan` but the values between the 2 dates